# How to import large SQL file using mysql.exe through StreamReader -> StandardInput

Tags: c#, mysql

I have .sql file (550 MB) and I want to import it to running mysql server. I know path to mysql.exe.

My idea is to immitate command line import `mysql -u user -ppass db_name < file.sql`. This from command line works well (I have set high max_allowed_packet). According to another thread here on Stackoverflow I found this working:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = mysqlexepath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -u user -ppassworddbname";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

try
{
    process.Start();
    StreamWriter input = process.StandardInput;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sqlfilepath))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (process.HasExited == true)
                throw new Exception("DB went away.");

            input.WriteLine(line);
            input.Flush();
        }
    }
    process.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I can see how tables are being created in DB. BUT my problem is that in about half the process exits. I was googling for some timeout settings but couldnt find anything.

I also tried to read file first:

```
var file = FileInfo(sqlfilepath);
StreamReader reader = file.OpenText();
string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
StreamWriter input = process.StandardInput;
input.AutoFlush = true;
input.Write(fileContents);
input.Close();
```

But I get OutOfMemory exception. So the proper way doesnt lead through string.

I would be very thankful for any advice how to find out where is the problem. I dont even know if its Process timeout or mysql timeout or if the problem is in StreamReader.

Comment: For you information I solved this simply by making .bat file which runs "mysql < sqlfile" in Temp directory and executing it. It worked but I am still curious what is causing the crash.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your problem, honestly I'm not sure what is wrong with your approach.  I can help by sharing how we run very large sql scripts using mysql.exe...

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql.exe" -C -B --password=[password] -P 3306 --user=[username] --host=localhost --database=[database] -e "\. C:\Backups\Mybackup.sql"`

Most of these parameters are obvious, connection info, etc.

What isn't obvious is the magical part `-e "\. [filename]"` the `-e` parameter specified that mysql should run the following command and exit.  The prefix `"\. "` indicates that an input file should be used and is followed by that file name.

We use this to restore multi-gigabyte databases without issue.  So here is the complete 'run a scirpt' with mssql...

```
public static int RunMySql(string server, int port, string user, string password, string database, string filename)
{
    var process = Process.Start(
        new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql.exe",
            Arguments =
                String.Format(
                    "-C -B --host={0} -P {1} --user={2} --password={3} --database={4} -e \"\\. {5}\"",
                    server, port, user, password, database, filename),
            ErrorDialog = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        }
        );

    process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data);
    // process.Start(); NOTE: NO need to start the process, because Process.Start has already started the process
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

Comment: One can use SQL inline w/ a suffix of the above example of \"{5}\"" where 5 = SQL instead of a file name

Comment: Isn't it the case in your code example that the process is started twice (the first time with `var process = Process.Start()`, and the second time when you call `process.Start()`) ?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!.. I was beating my head against the desk wondering why the `<` wasn't working in my .Net Process but was on the cmd line.  The `-e` was the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was too stubborn to use the accepted solution, even though it has gone unchallenged for two years. Also, I wanted to import from a .gz without first decompressing it to another file (and didn't want to have to assume a gzip executable was available). So I worked out what was wrong with the original code.

MySQL dump files can have very long lines with no breaks, so my guess is that `ReadLine()` is filling up a buffer without ever finding a newline character, causing the `OutOfMemory` exception. So `Read()` has to be used instead of `ReadLine()` to avoid this.

The other problem that may occur (which I had) is with binary blobs within a .sql file, which can get messed up by the text re-encoding when moving text strings from a file to stdin, so I've modified the code to avoid using Readers or Writers, instead using bytes and binary.

Here's my solution:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = mysqlexepath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -u user -ppassworddbname";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
int count;

try
{
    process.Start();
    BinaryWriter stdinBinary = new BinaryWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);

    Stream fileStream;
    if (sqlfilepath.EndsWith(".gz")) {
         fileStream = new GZipStream(new FileStream(sqlfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), CompressionMode.Decompress); 
    } else {
         fileStream = new FileStream(sqlfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    }

    using (fileStream)
    {
        while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            if (process.HasExited == true)
                throw new Exception("DB went away.");

            stdinBinary.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            stdinBinary.Flush(); // probably not needed
        }
    }

    stdinBinary.Flush();
    process.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I'm importing a 1.1 GB sql.gz database dump (3.5 GB uncompressed) without any problems, but I'd welcome any code improvements.

Comment: +1 With this option the process and method lifecycle stay in sync which is very useful if you want to do something else with the .sql files afterwards. The accepted answer didn't work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced so many problems, the issue is not the code, your code is correct, the problem is the limit of virtual memory that the computer does not support working with a file that big on memory per process. The system of Windows processes limits the amount of memory that executes each process to prevent the system crashes.

I do not know the limit because it varies for each computer architecture and the amount of memory, bus, etc. ..

An advice would you from the file, creating tables in sequence, read a piece run, read another run, and so on.

Another idea would be to try to work in parallel on another thread or process, watch this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C

Answer (score 0):

When debugging .NET application, windbg+SOS is a good tool to choice.

- install SOS extension for windbg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx
- start your program by windbg
- when exception happens, check the HEAP Objects and CallStack to specific Exception object in HEAP, to find the reason.
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/01/11/i-am-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-how-can-i-troubleshoot-this.aspx
- gcroot command can find references to Object in HEAP.
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/23/net-memory-leak-case-study-the-event-handlers-that-made-the-memory-baloon.aspx